Outdoor faucet will leak even after changing washer in stem
One of my outdoor water faucets was leaking from the handle part when it was shut off. I removed the stem brought it to a store and they added a washer at the end with a screw on it (see picture).

I put the stem back in (I had to push) and now it doesn't seem to be leaking from where the stem is (it leaks just a liiiitle bit) when it's closed, but instead is leaking from the normal output (I don't know the name, basically where you connect the hose). What I notice is that when I turn the handle to open the valve, it never stops. It stops when I turn to close it, it reaches a point where I can't close it more.
Here is how the stem looks like:

I have a couple of questions...

What else can I do to fix this?
If I can't fix it, since I'm not using this faucet a lot, how can I close both holes (the one where the stem goes, and the one where you would attach a hose)? I have a cap for the hose one, but it leaks water, even when it's all the way screwed.


The valve is a "frost-free" or "hydrant" type, designed to prevent the valve from freezing by keeping it in a warmer area (below frost-line or inside the house).
If the faucet leaks around the stem, then the O-ring and plastic washer are leaking. Those can be replaced easily, or the entire valve-stem can be replaced. The O-ring and end washer likely would be only US$1 or 2, but the valve stem, such as these at Amazon run from US$15 and up. The entire valve assembly costs not much more (these from Amazon start at US$16), but requires the labor of plumbing in the new valve through the wall.
In addition, if the valve leaks when *off, whether around the stem or from the spigot, the washer installed at the store has not fixed that issue.

It could be there is debris in the valve body. Try fishing any out with a hooked rod, and flush with a burst of water pressure.
It could be the valve seat has been damaged, and needs to be repaired. For most valves, one has access to the valve seat, but the frost-free valve seat is deep inside the body of the valve, and requires a specialized tool, as show and Williams.

So, you have a few choices:

Clean out the valve body.
Put a new O-ring and plastic washer on the valve stem.
Repair the valve seat.
Replace the valve stem.
Replace the whole valve.

It's your decision what would work best in your circumstances.

This is a fantastic answer. I will try many of the methods here, starting with trying to clean the valve body. It's weird that when I took the stem, there was no washer at all... One question though: how do I know the type of stem I need to buy, if I want to replace that?


Look at the valve body, both inside the house and underground, for a manufacturer's name or valve model number, and look that up online fro a picture to verify it's correct. 2. Bring the valve-stem to a knowledgeable person (e.g., plumber or staff at a plumbing-supply store. 3. Measure the valve stem, and just look for a matching image, with dimensions -- not very trustworthy, though.  BTW, straighten out a coat hanger and bend a small radius hook on the end to fish out debris.


If you have to add a washer to that stem, that means there was an old washer in there, correct? Did you pull that one out too? If not, my guess is that the old one is still in there and interfering with the sealing when you put the stem back in, which causes the leak. So, pull that out or just clean up the pipe's interior first, then replace the stem. Otherwise, you could try replacing the whole stem. Good luck!

Thank you! You are right, I didn't pull that one out, it didn't came with the stem when I pulled... What's the best way to clean that up?

A couple of ideas. First, shine the light into the hole. Hopefully you could see the old washer. If it's already destroyed broken into pieces, just spray inside with water (pull a hose from the other faucet) to clean it up. Otherwise, you might be able to just fish it with a long metal stick (like an oil dipstick from your car).
